# Encoding error with mailer module

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, mailer

When I use [the mailer module](https://bitbucket.org/ginstrom/mailer/src/c4f88a0091da8ef8d5327c2b529bc75f2f672692/mailer.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) (installed on Windows with pip) with python 2.7, I have an encoding error if I use non-ascii character.

For example, with the following snippet:

import mailer

```
message = mailer.Message()
message.From = "me@example.com"
message.To = "shan-x@server.com"
message.Subject = "Test"
message.Body = "Stuff with special characters like à or ç"

mailer = mailer.Mailer('my_relay-smtp')
mailer.send(message)
```

Then I receive the following email:

```
Stuff with special characters like ?? or ??
```

I've tried this:

```
message.Body = "Stuff with special characters like à or ç".decode('utf-8')
```

(Or with `encode`). But then I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is explicit in the help string for class Message:

> Use the charset property to send messages using other than us-ascii

So you should use:

```
message = mailer.Message(charset='utf8')
message.From = "me@example.com"
message.To = "shan-x@server.com"
message.Subject = "Test"
message.Body = "Stuff with special characters like à or ç".decode('utf-8')

mailer = mailer.Mailer('my_relay-smtp')
mailer.send(message)
```

Comment: How could I miss that? :/